# java.lang.NullPointerException and java.net.SocketException

Tags: java, sockets, exception, pointers, null

I’m trying to socket program in Java. Here the client sends a string which should be reversed by the server and sent back to the client. The server is a multithreaded server. Here is the client-side code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class ClientSystem
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            String hostname = "127.0.0.1";
            int port = 1234;

            Socket clientsocket = null;
            DataOutputStream output =null;
            BufferedReader input = null;

            try
            {
                    clientsocket = new Socket(hostname,port);
                    output = new DataOutputStream(clientsocket.getOutputStream());
                    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientsocket.getInputStream()));
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                    System.out.println("Error occured"+e);
            }

            try
            {
                    while(true)
                    {
                            System.out.println("Enter input string ('exit' to terminate connection): ");
                            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                            String inputstring = br.readLine();
                            output.writeBytes(inputstring+"\n");

                            //int n = Integer.parseInt(inputstring);
                            if(inputstring.equals("exit"))
                                    break;

                            String response = input.readLine();
                            System.out.println("Reversed string is: "+response);

                            output.close();
                            input.close();
                            clientsocket.close();
                    }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                    System.out.println("Error occured."+e);
            }
    }
}
```

Here is the server side code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ServerSystem
{
    ServerSocket server = null;
    Socket clientsocket = null;
    int numOfConnections = 0, port;

    public ServerSystem(int port)
    {
            this.port = port;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            int port = 1234;
            ServerSystem ss = new ServerSystem(port);
            ss.startServer();
    }

    public void startServer()
    {
            try
            {
                    server = new ServerSocket(port);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                    System.out.println("Error occured."+e);
            }

            System.out.println("Server has started. Ready to accept connections.");

            while(true)
            {
                    try
                    {
                            clientsocket = server.accept();
                            numOfConnections++;
                            ServerConnection sc = new ServerConnection(clientsocket, numOfConnections, this);
                            new Thread(sc).start();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                            System.out.println("Error occured."+e);
                    }
            }
    }

    public void stopServer()
    {
            System.out.println("Terminating connection");
            System.exit(0);
    }
}

class ServerConnection extends Thread
{
    BufferedReader br;
    PrintStream ps;
    Socket clientsocket;
    int id;
    ServerSystem ss;

    public ServerConnection(Socket clientsocket, int numOfConnections, ServerSystem ss)
    {
            this.clientsocket = clientsocket;
            id = numOfConnections;
            this.ss = ss;

            System.out.println("Connection "+id+" established with "+clientsocket);
            try
            {
                    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientsocket.getInputStream()));
                    ps = new PrintStream(clientsocket.getOutputStream());
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                    System.out.println("Error occured."+e);
            }
    }

    public void run()
    {
            String line, reversedstring = "";

            try
            {
                    boolean stopserver = false;
                    while(true)
                    {
                            line = br.readLine();
                            System.out.println("Received string: "+line+" from connection "+id);
                            //long n = Long.parseLong(line.trim());

                            if(line.equals("exit"))
                            {
                                    stopserver = true;
                                    break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    int len = line.length();
                                    for (int i=len-1; i>=0; i--)
                                            reversedstring = reversedstring + line.charAt(i);
                                            ps.println(""+reversedstring);
                            }
                    }
                    System.out.println("Connection "+id+" is closed.");
                  br.close();
                    ps.close();
                    clientsocket.close();

                    if(stopserver)
                            ss.stopServer();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                    System.out.println("Error occured."+e);
            }
    }
}
```

I get a java.lang.NullPointerException on the server side code when I enter the string and when i try to re-enter the string I get a java.net.SocketException: Socket closed exception.

Client side output:

```
Enter input string ('exit' to terminate connection): 
usa
Reversed string is: asu
Enter input string ('exit' to terminate connection): 
usa
Error occured.java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
```

Server side output:

```
Server has started. Ready to accept connections.
Connection 1 established with Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=3272,localport=1234]
Received string: usa from connection 1
Received string: null from connection 1
Error occured.java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I tried a lot but I don't get from where I get these exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These 3 lines are the culprits in the **client** code:

```
output.close();
input.close();
clientsocket.close();
```

Put them outside of the while loop, and in the finally block:

```
try {
    while(true) {
      // client code here
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace(); //  notice this line. Will save you a lot of time!
} finally {
    output.close(); //close resources here!
    input.close();
    clientsocket.close();
}
```

The issue is that as it was originally, you closed every resource, but in the next iteration, you wanted to use them agai, without initialising them...

#### Sidenote

Properly handling exceptions including proper logging of them. Always use either a logging framework like `log4j`

```
LOG.error("Unexpected error when deionizing the flux capacitor",e);
```

, or the `printStackTrace()` method

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

And don't forget to include the line numbers in your code, if you post a stacktrace....

**EDIT**

For the reversed issue:

```
else
{
    int len = line.length();

    reversedString=""; //this line erases the previous content of the reversed string

    for (int i=len-1; i>=0; i--) { //always use brackets!!!
        reversedstring = reversedstring + line.charAt(i);
    }
    ps.println(""+reversedstring);
}
```

What happened? The reversedString just grew and grew with each iteration, without getting erased... This is why I like to declare my variables in just the most strict scope I need them.

**EDIT**

To make the **exit** command no tkill the server, this can be one (very simple) solution:

In the ServerConnection class:

```
while(true)
{
    line = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("Received string: "+line+" from connection "+id);

    if(line.equals("exit"))
    {
        break; //just stop this connection, don't kill server
    }
    else if(line.equals("stop"))
    {
        stopserver = true; //stop server too
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        int len = line.length();
        for (int i=len-1; i>=0; i--) {
            reversedstring = reversedstring + line.charAt(i);
        }
        ps.println(""+reversedstring);
    }
}
```

What is happening here? There is a new "command" `stop`, which makes the server stop, and the exit just exits the client, but does not stop the server itself...

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot :). But there's one more problem. When I enter the 1st string as "USA" it prints the reversed string as "ASU". But when I enter a new string, say "Hello", it prints "ASUolleH". But I just want it to print "olleH". How do I do that?

Comment: @user2201650 I edited my question, the reverse stuff is fixed too

Comment: One last question, is my Server code a multithreaded server? I want my Server to be a multithreaded server. Can you help me out here please?

Comment: @user2201650 Yes, it is a multithreaded server. This line `new Thread(sc).start();` creates a new Thread for each connections.

Comment: Oh alright. But I get the following output when the client connects to the server. "Server has started. Ready to accept connections.
Connection 1 established with Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=53120,localport=1234]"

At the client side it waits for my string to be inputted. Is this normal in the case of multithreaded server?

Comment: @user2201650 well, I think the first input is usually there to make the socket be open only for as short as possible time _before_ opening the socket from the client side, but otherwise than possible timeout issues it does work...

Comment: I think i got you. So are you sure if the server is multithreaded?

Comment: @user2201650 I got you: the _client_ is **not** multithreaded. That does not mean a thing about the _server_. You can try yourself: just start the client in two separate windows...

Comment: Just wanted to confirm if the server is multithreaded. thats it :) So the server is multithreaded right?

Comment: Thank you! I have one more doubt. I have 2 clients calling the server. Everything works fine but when I type "exit" on one of the clients (say client2), the server is closing. But I just want the connection for client2 to close and the client1 connection to still be open. How do I do that? Any idea? Would be of great help if you can help me here.

Comment: When I put the close() methods in the finally{} block, I get the following error: " unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown "

Comment: @user2201650 I think you should post these as new questions, because you will get help from all the people at [SO], by posting a comment here, only I get a notification. This compiler error happens if you have a `catch(IOException e)` after a `try` block that does not throw this Exception. The problem is, I can't see any catch blocks with that Exception, so I assume your code changed since the original question.

Comment: I'll post it as a new question then. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Can you help me here? I have 2 clients calling the server. Everything works fine but when I type "exit" on one of the clients (say client2), the server is closing. But I just want the connection for client2 to close and the client1 connection to still be open. How do I do that? Any idea? Would be of great help if you can help me here.

Answer (score 0):

in the 1st run of the loop you are closing all the connections which is causing the issue.
                            output.close();
                            input.close();
                            clientsocket.close();,move it down

Answer (score 0):

Your server is calling `br.readLine();` It will wait until the client sends it, but once you send a String you call:

```
  output.close();
  input.close();
  clientsocket.close();
```

That will release the resource and result in `br.readLine()` being `null`

`if (line.equals("exit")) {` Here line is null, therefore you cannot call equals.

`if ("exit".equals(line)) {` You can change it like this to prevent that exception here.

Move the close statements to a finally block, even in the server should, if you have an exception in the while, the close are never reached, that may cause memory leaks.

Client:

```
} finally {
  output.close();
  input.close();
  clientsocket.close();
}
```

Server:

```
} finally {
  br.close();
  ps.close();
  clientsocket.close();
}
```

Note: you can validate them before closing to ensure they are not null.

You may have to provide a case for the input being null anyway, either exit the loop, usually you would use something like this:
`if (null==line || "exit".equals(line)) {`

If the client sends a null, something is wrong.